# Connecting to a MySQL database on a remote server (Unix hosting) C#

Tags: c#, mysql, unix, connection, hosting

I have a mysql database on a remote server (Unix hosting),

- Server : Localhost via UNIX socket
- Type server : MySQL
- Server version : 5.1.73 - Source distribution
- Protocol Version : 10
- User : root@localhost
- Character Server: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- address: 91.121.118.66
- database : xxxxxx
- username:  root@localhost
- password : xxxxxxxx

I want  to access this database using C# in Visual Studio 2012:

I have an error.

Note: connecting to my local MySQL data base, it works well, I only get the error connecting remotely to my server.

Comment: Well as it says the only connection available on that server is through local host so you cannot connect to it remotely

Comment: And you ought to consider switching to a hosting provider that has a version of mysql released in this decade

Comment: Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html